# RoR or Django for web app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django

I'm looking at creating a web app (similar functionality to kickstarter)

However i'm not a programmer and my knowledge is very minimal & i'm looking for one to help.

I'm about to post this on freelancer, should the project be built in RoR or Django?

What is the quickest + the best quality?

Thanks for your help

Jake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, a Kickstarter Clone: https://github.com/lockitron/selfstarter.

Answer (score 1):

If you're thinking about what the project should be built in, Django or RoR, both of which are great choices, then you should really consider the strengths of who will help you. If that person has more experience with RoR, then RoR. If they have more experience with Django, then Django. At such an early stage in a project, deciding between great frameworks that will get the job done is micro-optimization that could wait a while (I don't think there are many if any drawbacks between choosing one over the other performance-wise). Thus, the choice should come from team dynamics and what the team building the product is most comfortable with.

In this case, you don't have a team, but if you were to find someone or some people, and they were all proficient in RoR, then RoR would be the clear choice. If, on the other hand, you are planning on learning web development, and are asking which you should learn, my personal choice would be RoR.